# Validation on Start and End date by Text-view in android

Tags: android, date

how do i check/validate in Android whether end date [textbox] is greater than start date [textbox]?

I have displayed Current date in th initial time.. By the run time, i will change the Starting and end date..

While changing the Start date, the End date must be Greater than the Start date...

Help me to achieve this..

Comment: By Comparing Start and End Dates???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this function.

```
public static boolean isDateAfter(String startDate,String endDate)
    {
        try
        {
            String myFormatString = "yyyy-M-dd"; // for example
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormatString);
            Date date1 = df.parse(endDate));
            Date startingDate = df.parse(startDate);

            if (date1.after(startingDate))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

It return true if enddate is after start date. You can change date format as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much, and i have used DatePicker for changing the date in my application... If i used the end date as lesser than the start date means, it shold raise a warning.. can i do?

Comment: @Gowrishankar when you change data using datepicker and set it to textview before that you need to pass and startdate and enddate in this function and show message to user as per return value by the functuion.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void initViewValue(){
    newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

}
private void initViewEvents(){

    btn_start_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            fromDate();
        }
    });

    btn_end_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toDate();
        }
    });

}





private String  changeDate(String strStartDate){
    SimpleDateFormat readFormat = null, writeFormat = null;
    Date startDate = null, endDate = null;
    //  String strStartDate = "2014-12-09";

    readFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    writeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

    try {
        startDate = readFormat.parse(strStartDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return writeFormat.format(startDate);
}





private void fromDate(){
    fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            et_start_date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));

            getFromDate = et_start_date.getText().toString().trim();
        }
    },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    fromDatePickerDialog.show();
}
private void toDate(){
    toDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
            et_end_date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
            newDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 30);

        }

    },
            newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(`enter code here`Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    toDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(milliseconds(changeDate(getFromDate)));
    toDatePickerDialog.show();
}

public static long milliseconds(String date)
{
    //String date_ = date;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);
    System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + date);
    try
    {
        Date mDate = sdf.parse(date);
        long timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
        System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
        return timeInMilliseconds;
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```